# List key comparisons and return value

Tags: java, list, csv, arraylist, key

I want to compare keys of two different arraylists say

```
List<DataSt> list1 = new ArrayList<DataSt>();
List<DataSt> list2= new ArrayList<DataSt>();
```

DataSt is:

```
public class DataSt {

    public String key;
    BigDecimal time;
    BigDecimal memory;


    public DataSt(String key,BigDecimal time, BigDecimal memory)
    {
        this.key=key;
        this.time=time;
        this.memory=memory;
    }
}
```

list1:

```
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.collectionsSort,6691.679,5454>
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.abcdSort,5151.45,54545>
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.saasSort,5454.54,21212.2>
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.xyzSort,888.22,2115>
```

list2:

```
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.xyzSort,7448.362,7887.2>
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.abcdSort,951.5,4512.5>
<org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.lmnSort,4454.54,455.2>
```

And if they match eg., "org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.xyzSort" so I want to return the `<Key,time,memory>` of both list1 and list2 i.e., it must return

```
org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.xyzSort,888.22,2115
org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.xyzSort,7448.362,7887.2


org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.abcdSort,5151.45,54545
org.openjdk.jmh.samples.JMHSortBenchmark.abcdSort,951.5,4512.5
```

because I want to process the difference between their values and compare them i.e., 888.2,2115 in list1 and 7448.362,7887.2 in map2 thereby logging the difference to a csv file.

I used the following code:

```
public static List<DataSt> outputComparator(List<DataSt> list1, List<DataSt> list2) {

        List<DataSt> map4 = new ArrayList<DataSt> ();

        for (DataSt  entry: list1) {
            if (list2.contains(entry.key)) {
                saveRecord(entry, **//Here I want to return DataSt of list2//**,entry.key,map4);
            } else {
                saveRecord(entry.key, map4);
            }
        }

        for (DataSt entry: list2) {
            if (!(list1.contains(entry.key))) {
                saveRecord(entry.key, map4);
            }
        }
        return map4;
    }
```

The `"entry"` in statement `"saverecord"` returns `"list1.key, list1.time, list1.value"` for that run

Here I am not sure how to get `"DataSt part of list2"`. Can someone help me how do I retrive `"list2.key, list2.time, list2.value"` when `"list1.key == list2.key"` (Refer commented field in saveRecord()).

Comment: `list2.contains(entry.key)` will always be false, because `list2` contains objects of type `DataSt`, and `entry.key` is a `String`, and they are never equal. --- It's also weird to see a `List` named `map4`, especially since an actual `Map<String, DataSt>` would be so much easier to use for the purpose.

Comment: `list2.contains(entry.key)` returns `true` if a list element in `list2` equals `entry.key`.  Since the elements of `list2` are `DataSt` and `entry.key` is a `String`, they will never be equal, and `list2.contains(...)` always returns false.

Comment: @Andreas yes previously it was Map<String, DataSt> but I was requested to change it to List<DataSt>.... So how do I compare two lists and return values as above?

Comment: Who requested you change it, and why?

Comment: Whoever made that request is misguided.

Comment: @Andreas actually this is just a small part of the implementation but the larger part is of List<DataSt>... And so there is no other way..... Is it not possible to compare two lists and retrieve values????

Comment: Also, if you need a `List`, that doesn't mean you can't also have a `Map`.  I've run into more than one situation where I need to keep the same data in both collections.

Comment: "Is it not possible to compare two lists and retrieve values"... It's possible, but inefficient and clunky to do it without a `Map` or `Set`.

Comment: What if there is more than one key matching in `list2`?

Comment: Actually that doesn't happen ... only cases are as I've given in the example..

Comment: @ajb so I copied both the list to two new Hash maps of form <String,ListSt> where ListSt has time,memory. And with this I achieved the answer for my question. Is it the best way to do that?

Comment: Can't tell without looking at the whole code.  If it's working, consider posting your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and asking for comments.

Comment: @ajb check this out.... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171178/optimization-on-list-key-comparisons-and-return-value-with-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

`list2.contains(entry.key)` doesn't do what you think it does. It has no idea that `DataSt.key` is actually a key. You are trying to match a String object to a DataSt object (which will never work).

You could override `equals` to just compare the keys or you could write your own `DataSt findItem(ArrayList<DataSt> list, String key)`

If you really need keyed data you could look into a different structure where you can actually lookup by key.

Comment: Overriding `equals` seems like a bad idea.  There are better ways.

Comment: Suggesting to continue to do sequential search of a list is bad form, in my opinion.

Comment: @Andreas so I copied both the list to two new Hash maps of form <String,ListSt> where ListSt has time,memory. And with this I achieved the answer for my question. Is it the best way to do that?

Comment: @Andreas check this out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171178/optimization-on-list-key-comparisons-and-return-value-with-hashmap and please suggest optimizations if any....